# Matrix table with different values in different rows and sum them in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services

I have to create an SSRS report that look like below one.Entered into City A & Leaved From City B are in one Matrix and Leaved From City C is in different Matrix table. And these are the fields that I am getting from the Dataset and the last % field Is the calculated one by A/C. Since the A is in different Matrix table I am not able to get that value for doing calculation.

```
Information         January February    March   April   May June    July    August

Entered into City        A                          
Leaved From City         B  
    TOTAL COUNTS AND ENTERED % OF COUNTS ARE MENTIOEND BELOW                    
Total Count in City      C                          
%of Ppl Entered         A/C
```

The reason for using two datasets is I am having a Separate heading at the middle of the Table.
Could you please suggest on this

Comment: Can you refer to the ReportItem that holds the value of A?

Comment: I did that but Report item needs the items should be present in the same scope. Since i am using two Matrix table, A is present in first matrix table and C is in 2nd matrix table.

Comment: No, ReportItems does not care about scope, as long as the items are unique and on the same report.   Why do you think it does?   How did you code it, and what error did you get?

Comment: I am using the below code in the Expression at A/C
=ReportItems!Txn_Count8.Value + ReportItems!Txn_Count6.Value

And i am getting the error of
"The value expression of the "textbox3" refers to the report item Txn_Count6. Report Item expression can only refers to the other report items whithin the same grouping scope or containing a grouping scope"

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this is by creating a hash table in your report code to store city values and then get the city values as needed. The report code would look like below:

```
Dim cityTotals As System.Collections.Hashtable

Public Function AddCityValues(ByVal city As Object, ByVal amount As Object)
        If (cityTotals Is Nothing) Then
            cityTotals = New System.Collections.Hashtable
        End If
        If (Not cityTotals.Contains(customer)) Then
            cityTotals.Add(city, amount)
       End If
AddCityValues = amount
End Function

Public Function GetCityValues(ByVal city)
    If (Not cityTotals.Contains(city)) Then
        GetCityValues = 0
    End If        
        If (cityTotals.Contains(city)) Then
            For Each cityPair As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry In cityTotals
                If cityPair.Key.ToString() = customer Then
                GetCityValues = cityPair.Value
            End If
        Next
        End If
End Function
```

In your report expression, in order to add values to your hash table use the AddCityValues function like so:

```
=Code.AddCityValues(Fields!CityName.Value,Fields!Amount.Value)
```

In order to get the values later in the report use the GetCityValues like so:

```
=Code.GetCityValues(Fields!CityName.Value)
```

You can make the string key concatenated values in order to store and get more granular data.